# Apple maps memory footprint

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, ios6-maps

Did anyone had or have problems with the memory footprint (Live Bytes) when using the new Apple maps in an iPad application?
I tested my iPad app with Instruments and it seems the memory allocation jumps to over 70MB when displaying the map (and even 120MB when start zooming) -- while on iOS 5.1 (using Google Maps) the memory footprint is less than 4MB.
Or does anyone have a solution to this issue (reducing the memory footprint when using Apple maps)?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same Problem ! the app with google map is using avg 3-4 mb memory while running !! while app with new tomtom Map is using 35-40 mb memory for same !! Hope apple will resolve this issue !!

Comment: Having the same issue here, especially when zooming in the map.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, this became an issue required me to bang my head against a wall for some time. The straight answer is, yes this is an issue Apple accepts to be exists but they have some good excuses for that such as newer hardware devices should be able to handle this memory consumption without much pain. However, some people have already logged issues in their system, so there is nothing we can do until they fix it and release a patch.